# Joomla how to create pages with different templates or how to separate landing page style and blog page style

Tags: php, html, joomla

I am mobile developer and usually I don't work with cms and other web things. But of course for example Joomla is simple and everyone can use. I am new in it and my question is about how to setup landing page and Joomla that will work together.

So I hava landing page. There are two files:

CCS and HTML

So, as all of sites in the net mine has top menu as well. And of this menu will be linked to the blog.

So I want have landing page without Joomla and my Blog will use Joomla CMS. My landing page and my blog page has different stiles and that's why I want to separate it. Maybe you know another solution and can suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign two different templates to the landing page and blog. You can make your own Joomla template and I'd recommend using the Protostar template that comes with Joomla as a base.